# how to check received message is read or unread in xmpp framework in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, xmppframework

i am developing chat application using xmppframework and i am successfully completed the send and receive message , but

1)  if i am chat with user A and user B send me message the how can i identify the user B send me the message.  (i already maintain the messages in core data so message will be saved)
2)  how can i identify the **received** message is read or unread

NOTE : for message saving i used

```
 xmppMessageArchivingStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
 xmppMessageArchivingModule = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageArchivingStorage];
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have look to [XEP-0184](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html)

This should be the message stanza format

```
<message
    from='sender@domain/resource'
    id='messageId-1010'
    to='receiver@domain/resource'>
  <body>your message </body>
  <request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/>
</message>
```

And This is received response message

```
<message
    from='receiver@domain/resource'
    id='packetId'
    to='sender@domain/resource'>
  <received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='messageId-1010'/>
</message>
```

Here `messageId-1010` will be unique to get you know which message response it is.

Comment: as a role of receiver : i am at list of online users and some one send me message then how can i identify whose send me the message ??

Comment: In message stanza must have `from` attribute. from attribute value is the sender JID

Comment: I think you are not getting me .. i am asking about receiver and XEP-0184 in that all about sender functionality

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya what is your problem exactly. XEP-0184 for only to report delivery status of message. When you received message surely you are able to get sender JID. Same when receipet response will come here also JID is there in stanza packet. If you are a receiver you must have your JID.

Comment: i want to separate out the read and unread message in my apps. (like whats app:-> 1 new message ) any one send me message that i am storing but how can i identify that message is un-readed or not ??

Comment: Once when you send a message that time Make msgDeliveryStatus to `Not Delevered` once you got delivery packet response then change it to `Delivered`. Here message is very important. Which I mentioned in Answer.

Comment: i am not understand what you say .. sorry for that . if you don't mind, please help me.... really what i want that tell you with example : -- in whatsapp the you are sent me the message and currently i am chat with another person .. means i am not read your message that is unread message for me.. so whatsapp display that in bold-text. that i want... (i think you are done this kind of apps so give me some advice as well as some solution how go though that.. ) thanks.. :)

Comment: how can i set unique id, i mean any UIID or use timestamp as id ??

Comment: i set the message , as per your suggestion but i am not getting response :(

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre where do we need to save msgDeliveryStatus field? I will need to update msgDeliveryStatus for delivered and read state right?

Answer (score 3):

For users who are facing the same problem.

If you want to get the read receipts then instead of sending auto message delivery receipts, send it whenever user reads that message. Each message has it's corresponding message_id. Use that message_id to send the delivery receipt for the particular message that has been read. Add following line while making connection

```
    //message delivery
    XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts* xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts = [[XMPPMessageDeliveryReceipts alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
//don't write this line as it will send auto receipts whenever message will be delivered, but we want to send delivery receipts when user has read the message.
    //xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = YES;
    xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = YES;
    [xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts activate:self.xmppStream];
```

I have used 'chatStatus' attribute in my message entity. For sender I have kept value of chatStatus as sent, unsent, or received(received by other side or not). For Receiver Side I have kept the Values as read or unread(Have I read message or not, So that for unread message I could send read Receipts).

On Click Of send Button:

```
//Save to your Message Entity 

NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[m setObject: message_body forKey:@"message_body"];
[m setObject:messageID forKey:@"message_id"];
[m setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"isOutgoing"];
[m setObject:dateString forKey:@"date"];
[m setObject:timeString forKey:@"time"];
[m setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
[m setObject:yourId forKey:@"from"];
[m setObject:toId forKey:@"to"];

if (!Is_InternetAvailable]) {
 [m setObject:unsent forKey:@"chatStatus"];
}
else{
 [m setObject:sent forKey:@"chatStatus"];
}
[[CoreDataMethods sharedCoreDataMethods] saveUserMessage:m];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if ([message isoutGoing]) {//If I have sent the message

        // Mine bubble
        if ([[messageDict valueForKey:@"chatStatus"] isEqualToString:unsent]) {
            //set unsent image
        }
        else if ([[messageDict valueForKey:@"chatStatus"] isEqualToString:sent]){
            //set sent image
        }
        else if ([[messageDict valueForKey:@"chatStatus"] isEqualToString:received]){
          //set Received Image
        }
    }
    else{
        // Other Bubble , Notify them that you have read the message if it is unread/new message

        if ([[messageDict valueForKey:@"chatStatus"] isEqualToString:unread]) {

            //send read receipt
                NSXMLElement *receivedelement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"received" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:receipts"];

                NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message" xmlns:@"jabber:client"];
                [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:toId];
                [message addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:fromID];
                [receivedelement addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:[messageDict valueForKey:@"message_id"]];
                [message addChild:receivedelement];

                //XMPPMessage *generatedReceiptResponse = [[messageDict valueForKey:@"xmppMessage"] generateReceiptResponse];
                [[[kAppDelegate xmppHandler] xmppStream] sendElement:message];

                // update message entity
                [self updateChatStatus:read withMessageID:[messageDict valueForKey:@"message_id"]];
        }
    }
```

And finally when you receive the delivery Receipt in didReceiveMessage, update the chatStatus to received

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{

if ([message hasReceiptResponse]) {//message read
//Update database message entity
 [self updateChatStatus:@"received" withMessageID:[message receiptResponseID]];
}
}
```

You could set the values of chatStatus as per your requirement. As for unsent messages I have set it as sent in didSendMessage delegate.

**Note:** In my app I had to just show the read, sent and unset status, not the delivered status. If you also wanna show delivery status, then don't comment autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts and whenever messages are read send the IQ stanza to sender instead of delivery receipt and change the chatStatus accordingly.On sender side you have to take one one value for chatStatus sent, unsent, received, **delivered**.

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Can your please help me out for how to detect message is unread or read ?