# send xmpp message with push notification iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I want to send XMPP message in push notification in iOS application like Whatsapp does it.

When the user is in offline mode push received and also it received message packet with it.

How they are doing this?

Whatsapp also sends delivery report to receiver while app is in suspended state.

How they are doing this ?

Please explain with sample code.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using Openfire server,

1. For sending push notification, generate a plugin from code at below
   link and add that plugin in your openfire server.
   https://github.com/xinminlabs/openfire-apns-plugin
2. For received/read receipts, please go through following answer
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/20538390/2273094

I have used same things in one of my iOS application. Will be helpful to you also.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I am using ejabberd server

Comment: @Haripal Wagh: I am also facing the same issue as mentioned in this thread. I have installed the plugin as you mentioned. Cloud you pls tell me how can i access that plugin from my iOS application ?